# Django annotate queryset with list from related model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my first time using Django querysets in such detail so I am a little confused.

I have two models:

Asset (Django model but not managed by Django):

```
id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False)
asset = models.CharField(
    max_length=255, null=False
)
ip = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    null=True,
)
entity = models.ForeignKey(
    Entity,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="owned_assets",
    db_constraint=False,
)
```

Software (same as above – not managed by Django):

```
id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, editable=False, null=False)
entity = models.ForeignKey(
    Entity,
    db_constraint=False,
    null=False,
)
asset = models.ForeignKey(
    Asset, db_constraint=False, null=False
)
software = models.CharField(
    max_length=64, null=False
)
version = models.CharField(
    max_length=64, null=False
)
```

When a user GETs all assets, I want to decorate the Asset queryset with the related Software. A software entry is not unique across asset and entity though, a single asset can have multiple software entries associated with it. What would be the best way to go about annotating the base Asset queryset with these software entries? How do I add a list of `software` and `version` to a single Asset in the queryset?

Is it possible to do this in the DB and not in memory? Thank you

Comment: If you iterate over the `assets` queryset, you can lookup `asset.software_set.all()` to obtain all related `Software` objects. You can use `.prefetch_related(..)` to do the JOINing in "bulk" in memory, to avoid making an extra query to the database per `Asset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the relation in reverse with `asset.software_set.all()`, for example:

```
assets = Asset.objects.all()
for asset in assets:
    print((asset, asset.software_set.all()))
```

But this is rather inefficient, since for *N* `Asset` objects, it will make *N+1* queries to the database. First a query to fetch *all* the `Asset`s, and then a query per asset to fetch the related `software_set.all()` objects.

You can better make use of [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all related objects in memory with one extra query, and then JOIN at the Django/Python layer, so:

```
assets = Asset.objects..prefetch_related('software_set')
for asset in assets:
    print((asset, asset.software_set.all()))
```

Comment: Just saw your comment – this doesn't work. I get `AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute 'software_set'`, could this be because both tables are not managed by django?

Comment: @AJwr: the fact that these are not managed does not matter. The name of the relation (in reverse or not) does not depend on the database, it is a "conceptual layer" that Django builts on top of that. Is the name of the model (unmanaged or not) `Software`, did you specify a `related_name` in the `ForeignKey`? Perhaps it is better to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63078429/67579) the question and show the full details of the model classes.

Comment: Ah my mistake! I was trying it on an old machine that had not run the migration, this works well thank you